# How to properly configure Kundera programmatically with Spring Boot from @Bean methods?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, kundera

**I found an acceptable solution. Look below.**

I want to use Kundera as my persistence provider to store my JPA objects in HBase. I do everything in an annotation-driven way, i.e., I do not have and do not want a persistence.xml.

So far I did the following:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean bean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    bean.setPersistenceProviderClass(KunderaPersistence.class);
    final Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("kundera.dialect", "hbase");
    props.setProperty("kundera.client.lookup.class",
            HBaseClientFactory.class.getName());
    props.setProperty("kundera.cache.provider.class",
            EhCacheProvider.class.getName());
    props.setProperty("kundera.cache.config.resource",
            "/ehcache.xml");
    props.setProperty("kundera.ddl.auto.prepare", "update");
    props.setProperty("kundera.nodes", "myhbase.example.com");
    props.setProperty("kundera.port", "2182");
    props.setProperty("kundera.keyspace", "foo");
    bean.setJpaProperties(props);
    return bean;
}
```

I have an `ehcache.xml` with a default comfiguration in my `src/main/resources`.

When I try to run this, It bails out, the stack trace boils down to:

```
... many more ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No persistence units parsed from {classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml}
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.obtainDefaultPersistenceUnitInfo(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:655)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.determinePersistenceUnitInfo(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:358)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:307)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1613)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1550)
    ... 152 more
```

When I set a persistence unit name via `bean.setPersistenceUnitName("foo");` I get: `No persistence unit with name 'foo' found`

What am I doing wrong, Do I actually NEED a persistence.xml? I do not want one because I want to be able to set the configuration via command line switches. These are inserted into the `Environment` I can use as a parameter to my `@Bean` method and put into my properties object this way.

--- EDIT ---

I now created a `persistence.xml` with the basic settings, and just override the custom ones in my `Properties` object. This works, but now I have another problem, connecting to HBase locks up the Java process so badly I have to kill -9 it. Another question follows.

Comment: https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/wiki/Using-Kundera-with-Spring. This is a wiki page about using Kundera with spring

Comment: I know this page, but it uses XML configuration. I do everything programmatically. But my approach above, creating a persistence.xml and overriding some parameters programmatically, works.

Comment: You need to create a persistence.xml file in order to use Kundera. Can you share some logs that are generated while you app tries to connect to HBase via Kundera ?

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in my original edit, I found an acceptable solution:

1. Create a persistence.xml with the default settings
2. Override the custom settings in the @Bean method